# Auto resizing simple form with two listboxes

Tags: wpf, winforms, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a simple two-panel file manager (such as Total Commander or FreeCommander). So basically just two listboxes/listviews, one on left, one on right.

But I have hard time trying to make it responsive, when user resizes window either from left side or right side. I need those listboxes to change accordingly on main window/form size, but not cover the other one in process.

I tried on both WPF and WinForms. In WinForms, there is just an Anchor property, which probably can't handle resizing on both up/down and left/right, or I don't know how.

In WPF I know there are tons of ways how to do this, but I don't understand XAML at all, so I'm stuck.

If anyone ever faces similar problem and managed to deal with it, or just has an idea, how to make it work, I would welcome any kind of help.

Comment: If you're using WinForms, you're looking for the [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-arranging-controls-on-windows-forms-using-a-tablelayoutpanel).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB / C#: Resizing two controls equally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074819/vb-c-resizing-two-controls-equally)

Comment: if you are going to create a WPF application, then learn xaml. it is a "must have" skill. `Grid` with 2 `ColumnDefinitions` fits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

WPF solution: use a `Grid` width three columns. One for each `ListView` and one for the `GridSplitter` to make both `ListView` columns resizable.

```
<Window>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListView Grid.Column="0" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" />
    <ListView Grid.Column="2" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

But I'm afraid this solution won't safe you from learning WPF and especially XAML.